# Link errors with libcurl

Tags: c++-cli, linker-errors, libcurl, name-decoration

I include and use libcurl for a project and I get this error

```
unable to generate p/invoke for "function_declaration" decorated_name; calling convention missing in metadata
```

and others.
I code with visual studio c++
Ive searched those and I read that there might be a problem with the library, which was compiled from C files. My project is in c++/cli. Do you think that's the problem? what could I do?

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
```

that's includes that I'm using

that's the code

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    return written;
}

int main()     
{
    CURL *curl_handle;
    static const char *headerfilename = "head.out";
    FILE *headerfile;
    static const char *bodyfilename = "body.html";
    FILE *bodyfile;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://url");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,   CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, headerfile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, bodyfile);
    curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    fclose(headerfile);
    fclose(bodyfile);
}
```

[link error LNK2031](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms173734%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

[link error LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/799kze2z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
and others

```
  : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
   : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" enum CURLFORMcode __clrcall curl_formadd(struct curl_httppost * *,struct curl_httppost * *,...)" (?curl_formadd@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLFORMcode@@PAPAUcurl_httppost@@0ZZ)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
   : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" struct curl_slist * __clrcall curl_slist_append(struct curl_slist *,char const *)" (?curl_slist_append@@$$J0YMPAUcurl_slist@@PAU1@PBD@Z)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
   : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
  : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
  : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
  : error LNK2031: p/invoke konnte nicht für ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z)" generiert werden. In den Metadaten fehlt die Aufrufkonvention.
  : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000016) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
   : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00001A) "extern "C" enum CURLFORMcode __clrcall curl_formadd(struct curl_httppost * *,struct curl_httppost * *,...)" (?curl_formadd@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLFORMcode@@PAPAUcurl_httppost@@0ZZ).
   : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00001B) "extern "C" enum CURLFORMcode __clrcall curl_formadd(struct curl_httppost * *,struct curl_httppost * *,...)" (?curl_formadd@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLFORMcode@@PAPAUcurl_httppost@@0ZZ).
   : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000020) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
   : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000021) ""extern "C" struct curl_slist * __clrcall curl_slist_append(struct curl_slist *,char const *)" (?curl_slist_append@@$$J0YMPAUcurl_slist@@PAU1@PBD@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
   : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000026) ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
  : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000027) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
   : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A000028) ""extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
   : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00002A) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
 : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00002B) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
  : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00002C) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
  : error LNK2020: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00002D) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ).
   : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00002E) ""extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ)", auf das in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
 : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00002F) ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)" verwiesen wird.
  : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" enum CURLFORMcode __clrcall curl_formadd(struct curl_httppost * *,struct curl_httppost * *,...)" (?curl_formadd@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLFORMcode@@PAPAUcurl_httppost@@0ZZ)".
  : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" struct curl_slist * __clrcall curl_slist_append(struct curl_slist *,char const *)" (?curl_slist_append@@$$J0YMPAUcurl_slist@@PAU1@PBD@Z)" in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)".
 : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z)" in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)".
  : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z)" in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)".
   : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)".
  : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ)" in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)".
 : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_global_init(long)" (?curl_global_init@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@J@Z)" in Funktion ""private: void __clrcall freerice::Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork(class System::Object ^,class System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs ^)" (?backgroundWorker1_DoWork@Form1@freerice@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVDoWorkEventArgs@ComponentModel@4@@Z)".
```

Comment: @mu is too short: passing a C++ function to C library is not a problem as a function pointer is passed not the name so name-mangling won't cause trouble here.

Comment: @mu: My german is good enough to read them. First one: : `error LNK2031: p/invoke could not be generated for XYZ. The calling convention is missing from the metadata.` To me this seems related to cli with which I'm not very familiar.

Comment: @mu: Basically there are three groups of messages. The last group could come from a missing curl library. But -lcurl probably doesn't work for Visual Studio. Third post on the following page http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?273849-Studio-Visual-C-Adding-(.lib)-refrence! explains how to add a lib.

Comment: Voting to close since the OP fixed their problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to include some files related to the libcurl now I don't get any linker errors